# Static BroadcastReceiver not Working after Installation from ADB

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, adb

I working on a project that need to launch an app by broadcasting a customized intent "com.example.demo.action.LAUNCH" via adb.

My plan is to statically register a broadcast receiver "LaunchAppReceiver" that will launch the app when receiving the customized intent.

I installed the .apk by calling

```
adb install -r <pakcageName>
```

then I sent the intent by calling

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.demo.action.LAUNCH
```

However, nothing happened after the intent was sent. It seemed the broadcast receiver didn't receive the intent at all. Do I need to somehow instantiate the receiver before it can receive the intent?

**Note:** Since the android device is remote, I have to use adb to handle the installation and the launch.

Thanks!!

---

I declared the broadcast receiver as follow

```
public class LaunchAppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public LaunchAppReceiver () {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(newIntent);
    }
}
```

and statically registered it in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:enabled="true">
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.demo.LaunchAppReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.demo.action.LAUNCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Seems like you need to run the application at least one time to register a broadcast in the system.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be true... Now the case is I plan to launch the app from the broadcast receiver, which however needs to run the app to be registered... Stuck in a loop.

Comment: Hmm... I think that should work.. Do you see any errors on your logcat?  Is LaunchAppReceiver in the correct package (com.example.demo.LaunchAppReceiver)?

Comment: Finally got this solved. Please see my answer below:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally got this fixed.

Since Honeycomb, all the freshly installed apps will get into a **STOP** stage until they are launched for at least one time. Android adds a flag "**FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES**" for all broadcast intents, which stops them from reaching the stopped apps.
http://droidyue.com/blog/2014/01/04/package-stop-state-since-android-3-dot-1/

To solve this issue, just simply add the flag "**FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES**" to the intents we send. In my case, I modify the adb command as

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.demo.action.LAUNCH --include-stopped-packages
```

Comment: Logged in just to upvote this answer. Thank you! :')